# display slitly red color bar when push the view when navigation bar is hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

in my apps,  navigation bar is hidden, when i push to the another view i see the slightly red color bar at top when push view animation is complete bar also remove.

i am hide the navigation controller before push to view using

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

if i am put this code in viewdidload method then also display redcolor bar

for example : 
View Controller A :

```
-(void)viewDidload
{
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}

-(IBAction)pushtoView:(id)sender
{
   ViewContolB *obj =[[ViewContolB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewContolB" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; in ur ViewContolB viewDidLoad.

Comment: @DheerajSingh thanks for replay.. if i am hide from the appDelegate and never again call for show then also it display..

Comment: try this: In ViewControlB, in viewDidLoad add this line: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: @OnikIV also try but same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an background image or a tint color to set the background of the navigation bar?

If you use a background image (which it sounds like since you have a solid gray background), you need to make sure it is 64 points tall (128 pixel in retina). If you use the old iOS 6 dimensions (44 points), iOS 7 will fall back and not have it include the status bar.

For details of this behavior, check out Table 5-1, "Treatment of resizable background images for bars at the top of the screen" in the iOS 7 transition documentation.

Also, if this is the case you shouldn't need to set the edgesForExtendedLayout, extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars and View controller-based status bar appearance. You might need it for other stuff - but not for this.

If you want to still support iOS 6, you need to have two different background images, one of iOS 7 and above and a legacy version of iOS 6 and below. That should get you the effect you are looking for.